# Can '더럽게' be used to mean that something is very *good*, as well as very *bad*?

Tags: word-usage

I suppose 더럽게 재미없다 Literally means something 'dirtily lacking fun', so the meaning in more natural English is something like 'absolutely not fun'.

Does it seem natural to say '더럽게 재미았다' for something that's very fun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would say 더럽게 재밌다 for being sarcastic, "I don't want to admit this, but it's pretty fun."

더럽다 doesn't pair well with anything positive.

Comment: As a native Korean, I don't think so. The literal meaning of ‘더럽다’ would be negative, however, sometimes I saw someone uses ‘더럽게’ as neutral ‘extremely’.  “더럽게 웃기네 ㅋㅋㅋ” “I found this funny so badly LOL” But this seems old-fashioned, is not used by the yonger generation.

Comment: To clarify, I meant to say that it sounds old and vulgar to use "더럽다" to modify something positive. It's not as extreme as using f--ing or ㅈㄴ to modify a positive action, but similar in the tone it gives off.

Comment: +1 `더럽다 doesn't pair well with anything positive.`